# Can you avoid closure memory leaks by using functions instead?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, closures, rx-swift

So I'm using `RxSwift` and has a `function` that looks like this:

```
private func setAndVerifyTestmode(isOn: Bool) {
    parameterService.setTestMode(value: isOn)
      .flatMap { _ in self.parameterService.requestTestMode() }
      .subscribe( { [weak self] _ in
        //do stuff })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I noticed that I had forgotten to use `[weak self]` in the `.flatMap` so I added it like this:

```
private func setAndVerifyTestmode(isOn: Bool) {
    parameterService.setTestMode(value: isOn)
      .flatMap { [weak self] (_: Int?) in 
          guard let self = self else { return .just(nil) }
          self.parameterService.requestTestMode() }
      .subscribe( { [weak self] _ in
        //do stuff })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

But then it gave me an error: `Generic parameter Result could not be infered`

I couldn't get around it so I tried using a nested `function` instead of the `closure`, ending up with this:

```
private func setAndVerifyTestMode(isOn: Bool) {
    func requestTestMode(_: Int?) -> Single<Int?> {
      parameterService.requestTestMode()
    }
     
parameterService.setTestMode(value: isOn)
      .flatMap(requestTestMode(_:))
      .subscribe( { [weak self] _ in
        //do stuff })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Great, the compiler was happy and it works. And in my world this takes care of the memory leak issues since I'm no longer using a `closure` requiring a reference to `self`. **But**, a collegue of mine told me that this is the exact same thing as not using `[weak self]` in a `closure`; and that you are still subjected to `memory leaks` using a nested `function`. I can't really see that they are the same thing since there isn't even a reference to `self` anymore.

Anyway, the question I have is: Do I get around the issue with `memory leaks`, `self` and `[weak self]` using the nested function above, or is my collegue right: it's the same thing; there is no gain to what I did?

Comment: Sorry, I realize this is not what you asked, but let's go back one step. `weak self] (_: Int?) in self.parameterService.requestTestMode()` is indeed wrong. Why don't you just fix it? Change `self.parameterService` to `self?.parameterService`. I mean, the _whole point_ of `weak self` is that it turns `self` into an Optional so that it is not retained. To say `self` instead of `self?`, even if the compiler had not stopped you, would negate the entire purpose of the exercise: you are relating `self`, the very thing you said you didn't want to do.

Comment: If there is no `self` captured, how is `parameterService.requestTestMode()` eventually getting called?

Comment: I do regard the entire premise of the question as mistaken, however. The need for this `weak self` dance is because otherwise a strong reference to self is stored by self, leading to a retain cycle where self is not released when it should be. To find out if that's happening, implement `deinit` and log it. If it's happening, fix it. If it's not, do nothing. But don't keep using `weak self` in this knee jerk fearful automatic way. Answer your own question: was there a memory issue in the first place? If so, and only if so, did your syntactic games solve it? Yes or no?

Comment: relating > retaining

Comment: Also what the heck is this mysterious `(_: Int?)` incantation that pervades your code? Just get rid of it, please. It does nothing and it annoys the compiler.

Comment: @Sweeper It's getting called because `parameterService` is getting retained directly instead of indirectly through `self`.

Comment: @DanielT. Oh wow the compiler is smart enough to do *that*? Would the behaviour change if it were `self.parameterService.requestTestMode()` instead?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Sorry, the above is wrong. In either case, it would only capture `parameterService`.

Comment: @Sweeper My bad, I was wrong. The compiler is not smart enough to do that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, a collegue of mine told me that this is the exact same thing as not using [weak self] in a closure; and that you are still subjected to memory leaks using a nested function.

Your colleague is right. (This surprised me.)

Fortunately, there are easier ways:

The most obvious: `.flatMap { [parameterService] _ in parameterService.requestTestMode() }`
By capturing parameterService directly instead of indirectly through self, you avoid capture of self.

Another option: `.flatMap { [weak self] _ in self?.parameterService.requestTestMode() ?? .just(0) }`
The value to emit is problematic because you used a Single so you have to emit something. If you had used a Maybe or Observable, you could have just used `.empty()`

Like this: `.asMaybe().flatMap { [weak self] _ in self?.parameterService.requestTestMode().asMaybe() ?? .empty() }`

Lastly you could use a free function (one that is not bound to any class or struct) that is curried:

```
func requestTestMode(parameterService: ParameterService) -> (Int?) -> Single<Int?> {
    { _ in parameterService.requestTestMode() }
}
```

Which could be used like: `.flatMap(requestTestMode(parameterService: parameterService))`
And that is effectively the same as the first option I gave above.

Comment: I was just thinking to myself, "Hope Daniel T. responds because he always gives really great, clear, understandable answers". Many thanks @Daniel T.

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt I had to update my answer. I was incorrect in my initial assessment.

Comment: That is surprising! Thanks for clearing it up though!